# apt upgrade apparently "stuck" in a loop

Tags: apt, upgrade, cuda

Ubuntu 20.04.2

At the n-th `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` I got the message that

```
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  nsight-compute-2022.2.0 nsight-systems-2022.1.3
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  nsight-compute-2022.2.0 nsight-systems-2022.1.3
The following packages have been kept back:
  cuda cuda-drivers
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
Need to get 666 MB of archives.
After this operation, 885 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

I noticed the package names (of the "old" ones and the ones that will be installed) are the same, but I figured maybe they are different builds so I went ahead and hit Yes and then followed its suggestion to use `sudo apt autoremove`. At the following `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`, the message is exactly the same.

This seems strange to me because I would expect the packages to no longer be there after I autoremoved them and therefore not to get the message that they may be autoremoved again. Yet `apt` somehow finds them.

It appears to me that I'm kind of "stuck in a loop". Now, it's not really a big deal: I could just ignore the suggestion to autoremove them and my life would still be happy, but I'm kind of curious if anyone has seen this before and what may have caused it.

Comment: Try to `sudo apt remove` the two problematic packages and reinstall them again if you need them. I would also suggest that you run your update and upgrade commands separately because when you combine them, you may be missing out on important diagnostic information. Putting the commands together doesn't allow you to stop and review the information from one command before running the next.

Comment: I'm not sure which two problematic packages you mean: the "NEW" ones that will be installed and yet I could `autoremove` because "they are no longer required", or the ones that are being kept back and not upgraded?

Comment: Did you add a ppa to your system, especially one concerning video drivers? The output of `apt policy nsight-systems-2022.1.3` (and for the other packages: cuda, etc) would likely be instructive.

Comment: @OrganicMarble Yes, the PPA is there. For the `apt policy` thing I guess it's too late now: I solved the problem and the offer to install the "new" ones and autoremove the "old" ones is no longer there. It would still be interesting to know why it does that (it's not the first time I see it) , but I guess for that I'll have to wait until the next time it happens and then do the `apt policy` before fixing it.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted out!

Comment: Please post the details of your solution by submitting an answer to this question.

Comment: @Nmath What I did is not really an answer to this question: it made the "problem" (notifications) disappear, but the question of why the packages show up as automatically installed with the suggestion to autoremove them, after I already autoremoved them, still remains.

Comment: To answer that, we need a lot more information. My guess would be improper PPA use or bugs with the PPA or dependencies. Ubuntu is not responsible for PPAs and they often mess up package management.   Now, the purpose of Ask Ubuntu is to build a library of questions and answers about Ubuntu. What would be most helpful to others would be how you solved this problem. That's infinitely more valuable than an explanation. You ought to share that answer so it can benefit others. There is still room to provide an explanatory answer later, but let's think of others and not withhold your solution...